# showing large blocks of text in a modal html

Tags: website-design

I'm creating a site, trying to learn angularjs, and I've had some UX related issues.

I have an html modal that opens and shows some data. One of the pieces of data is a characters lore, which can be short, or very very long. There's a button above that can collapse or open the well.

EDIT: as I've said, I'm a total newbie to web design, so I would appreciate any tips constructive criticism you may have to offer!

[image: small well]

[image: big well]

Since I'm already using a modal, I would suppose it would be bad practice to open ANOTHER modal to show that info... How would you show that info... Maybe in the buttom of the modal? Thanks for helping!

Without lore
[image: widened no lore]

With lore
[image]

Comment: Your modal is awfully narrow. Could widening your existing modal solve your problem?

Comment: This is how modals are by default, I would suppose it would help, but it might not even be possible. I'll check that out.

Comment: It's definitely possible. That's where I'd start

Comment: I've done it, it still is kinda big. Mind telling me your opinion after I post an updated picture?

Comment: Why are you using a modal here and not a new screen? Modals should be used to focus a users attention on a simple interaction(s) that must be completed or canceled before the user continues. One sign you might be overloading a modal is if you're experiencing problems you're trying to solve with more modals. Showing this data on separate screen would solve your display issues. Do you have a strong reason for not doing this?

Comment: I would mostly say lack of experience, haven't yet tried redirecting to a new page... + there's the splash in the background that works really well with the modal, would kinda suck to lose it

Answer (score 2):

I would not show more than a paragraph of data in a modal window. Modals can be a real pain to navigate, especially for trackball users or ones with mobility issues. Any click outside of the window tends to close it, which leads to going back and reopening it. And if you control for that, then the user has to find the link to manually close it. Additionally, the information can't be linked to - so if a user wants to return to that page at a later time with a link they can't without remembering what they clicked.

I'd have a small amount of data, and if the user will digest a lot more than what you can show in a small modal window then provide a link to a stand alone page.

Comment: for now, I'll keep it in the modal, and if i'll want to move it to another page, i'll have an easier time because my directives are organized well

Answer (score 1):

Use progressive disclosure. Only show the user what they need to see when they need to see it. Provide only the relevant info for the character lore with a button to reveal more. Keep everything in the same modal window.

Comment: What do you mean? from what I understand, you're talking about not showing the character lore by default, and only when the button is pressed. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, if you provide too much information at once, they simply won't read it. But of course, all of our discussion is based on the user's context of use; what are their goals of using the character lore? What does the user need to accomplish? If you can discover your user "key tasks" you can keep these paths clear from clutter. Progressive disclosure can help in this regard. Google the term progressive disclosure.

Comment: I'm thinking about doing accordion styled tabs, so that the viewer knows what he can see, but he won't see it all at once, and he could also open some tabs together so that he won't have to switch between tabs much